# add text listener causing not found exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout

In NewTweetActivity.java, I have:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newtweet);
    listenToChange();
}

public void listenToChange(){
    TextView cEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tweetCountTextView);
    EditText tView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tweetComposerEditText);
    tView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            int len = (140 - s.length());
            cEditText.setText(len);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

However, it asks me to declare **cEditText** as final, but when I do, it fails to load the newtweet layout.

If I put the **cEditText** declaration inside `afterTextChanged`, it loads the layout, but when I trigger `afterTextChanged` (by typing in the EditText), it causes this:

```
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x8b
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2911)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at com.jgnzapps.quark.NewTweetActivity$1.afterTextChanged(NewTweetActivity.java:31)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6532)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:6720)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextHasChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:897)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:353)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:654)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:415)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:318)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:75)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3694)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-08 20:44:27.054: E/AndroidRuntime(4417):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

if I call the `setText` method of **cEditText** with a string ("cats", for example), it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is quite easy: You are trying to set a int as the Text and not a String.
Because of this, android executes this method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)
Which means, it searches for a String-resource with the given id, which doesn't exist.

You should set the text this way:

```
int len = (140 - s.length());
cEditText.setText(String.valueOf(len));
```

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for a len.toString() method, having gone straight from .NET to Java, and thought it needed conversion!

Comment: int is a primitive, it doesn't provide a toString(). You could have also made an Integer (Wrapper class) and call toString() there.

Comment: goddamnit! I also made the same mistake just now.